# Will Visual Studio 2010 database projects work with .Net 3.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I notice that Visual Studio 2010 database projects have a re-distributable component to support the deployment on end-user systems.

Will this component work against .Net 3.5, or does it require .Net 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, Visual Studio 2010 database projects will require .Net 4.0 on the target machine. If you inspect the redistributable components in *%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy* using Reflector, you'll see that they all depend on version 4.0.0.0 of the framework libraries.

In addition to this, the .deploymanifest files (which are really MSBuild files in disguise) specify 4.0 as the MSBuild tools version.

It looks like you would need to use [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edtion GDR R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed&displaylang=en) (which of course requires VS 2008) if you want to target .Net 3.5 on the database server.